# How to use String name in StringBuilder.AppendLine()?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use string name in appendline() function. The string named "programFiles" gets the program files location correctly, but I need to include it in append line (to write the path to the file) Tried this,

```
Dim programFiles As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.AppendLine("Your " & programFiles & "is working properly.")

File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata") & "\mytext.txt", sb.ToString())
```

But it doesn't write to a file. What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: What does mean "doesn't write"?

Comment: It means, it doesn't write the line to the file.

Comment: Application running without elevated privileges usually don't have write permissions to Program Files.

Comment: Do you receive an error? File changed but no new lines appear. Another line appears?. Be specific. Not just "my code doesn't work".

Comment: No errors, no change on the file. The only problem is including the string name incorrectly I guess.

Comment: are you trying to append your text to the text already in the file or are you calling that function multiple times before checking the file? because in that case you'll end up with something wrong. `File.WriteAllText` overwrites the the selected file.

your code seems right and thats the only ting i can think of that wasnt mentioned in the previous coumments

Comment: Yeah, looks like #1 cause - human error, i.e. you are not looking in the right directory.

Answer (score 3):

When I tried your code on my machine, it worked as I would have expected, the file c:\users\[myusername]\Appdata\Roaming\mytext.txt was created and contains one line

"Your C:\Program Files (x86)is working properly."

so obviously your VB is correct.  Maybe you're looking in the wrong subdirectory?